# Can't get Erlang based Riak to work under Ubuntu 9

Tags: ubuntu, riak

I have been unable to get Riak working under Ubuntu 9 due to many problems. I tried following the current blog:

http://onerlang.blogspot.com/2009/10/fighting-with-riak.html

: but still Riak is not working. Has anyone else had problems with Riak on Ubuntu 9?

I did get this working eventually by following this guide:

http://megam.info/2010/01/20/riak-strapping-up/

Also I have written my own guide on this as well:

http://riak1.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-do-i-install-riak-on-ubuntu-9.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please verify:

1. You have Erlang OTP release R13B03 installed.  I believe that Ubuntu 9 ships with R13B01.  You may need to download and build the latest release yourself from http://erlang.org/.
2. You have libssl installed (and possibly also libssl-dev).  The 'crypto' Erlang module requires that library.

If neither of these things fixes the problem, please post the output of:

```
riak$ ./rebar compile generate verbose=1
```

Comment: I eventually got this working, but had to follow the guide here:

http://megam.info/2010/01/20/riak-strapping-up/

The Basho documentation needs to be more clear.